# relationship filter in powerBI or powerpivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerbi, powerquery, ssas-tabular

i am using the powerBI tools (powerpivot) to create a data model. i am done the model. the model include the product, customer dimensions and sales fact table. i have made the relationship and hierarchy in the model. now i have a requirement to show the total revenue of all the customer who brought product 1,2,3.

for example customer A brought product 1 and product 5 and the total revenue from this customer is 50 so i want to show 50 as a result

customer B bought product 4 and i do not want to include this customer in my output.

i can do the same in microstratergy using relationship filter but how can i do the same in powerpivot or powerview or powerBI.

Please help
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you add data model to question? Also can you elaborate on desired result. Do you need total revenue of customer or revenue generated from product 1,3, 5 only?

Comment: I Want the total revenue of the customer not the revenue generated from the product 1,3,5 only

Answer (score 1):

1. In PowerPivot, relate Sales table with Customer table (Lookup table) and Relate Sales table to Product table (Lookup table).
2. Create following two measures

   ```
   [HasPurchased X Products] =
   OR (
       OR (
           CONTAINS ( Sales, Sales[ProductID], 1 ),
           CONTAINS ( Sales, Sales[ProductID], 3 )
       ),
       CONTAINS ( Sales, Sales[ProductID], 5 )
   )

   [DesiredMeasure] = 
   IF (
       Sales[HasPurchased X Products] = TRUE (),
       SUM ( [Amount] ),
       BLANK ()
   )
   ```
3. Select Customers in ROWS and add [DesiredMeasure] in VALUES, pivot table will show desired result.

Comment: Thanks Abhijeet, but doing this will show me the revenue of the selected items. whereas i want the list of customer who bought these items and there total revenue (not the revenue of the item they have choose for filter rather all the items which they have purchased)

Comment: @AtulBansal : Updated Answer. Check now.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to what Abhijeet said, which is a nice robust solution, you might also just filter the chart in Power View.  Assuming you have a relationship between sales and products table, you can select the chart in Power View, open the Filters pane, select per chart filters, add Product to the chart filters and filter to include only productions 1,2,3.  This will automatically calculate the measure.  Now Abhijeet's solution is better if you need that calculation to be reused.  This solution works great if you're in a 'what if' scenario where you'd like to say "what are the sales for products 1,2,3" and in another breath say "actually i'm interested in sales for products 2,3 only, so me that instead.".

HTH,
-Lukasz

http://dev.powerbi.com

http://blogs.msdn.com/powerbidev